# CXF Client Encryption , Decryption and Signing

Tags: security, cxf

I have developed the Web service client using CXF 3.0.0 .

When i am sending a WS request to the server i have to encrypt the header and body. The following is my cxf-client.xml configuration

```
 <jaxws:client name="{http://batchtransfer.em.emm.ericsson.com}PushFromBankBindingPort" createdFromAPI="true">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="com.ClientKeystorePasswordCallback"/>        
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="clientKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="clientKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="myservicekey"/>
        </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

When i trying to run client i am getting an exception saying that

> Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: Security
>   configuration could not be detected. Potential cause: Make sure
>   jaxws:client element with name attribute value matching endpoint port
>   is defined as well as a ws-security.signature.properties element
>   within it

The following is my wsdl port definitions.

```
<service name="PushFromBankBindingService">
    <port binding="iso:PushFromBankBinding" name="PushFromBankBindingPort">
    <soap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:9001/PushFromBankBindingPortImpl"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

And i have the clientKeystore.properties in a right place and keystore password also right.

But i don't know what is the problem. Please help

Comment: I'm not familiar with CXF, but why aren't you using SSL? Trying to encrypt at the HTTP layer, without protecting the underlying transport layer is going to be marginal at best.

Comment: I am using SSL as well , trying to use two level of security  transport level and message level as well